# How to enable POLine 301000 Custom Field when status open acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hi I have been surfing the forums for this I want to enable a custom text field on my poline when the status is open.
[image]

what i have done so far is edit the automation step
[image]

and then i added a code extension for my rowselected

```
 protected void POOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
       
      var row = (POOrder)e.Row;
        
            POOrder order = Base.Document.Current;
            if (order == null || row == null || Base.IsExport) return;

            if (order.Status == POOrderStatus.Open)
            {
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<POLineExt.usrvendordate>(cache, row, true);
             
               
            }

        }
```

that is what i have done so far but it is not being enabled
thank you i hope you can help me thanks in advance.

Comment: my guess without looking at it. If the view/cache for that type has AllowUpdate = false then it will not matter what is set as enable. To get around this should AllowUpdate = true, then disable all fields via SetEnable and then enable the line that should be enabled when not open.

Comment: @Brendan hi brendan thank you for the answer but it stil does not make it enabled

Comment: when extending a graph events be sure to use the signature with the row delegate so you can control when the base event is called. Use POOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del) and call del before your code. If still doesnt work then could be something from automation steps

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** 
**method 1: make 'vendordate' property "setreadonly" to false**
[image]

Did you find the path for the usrvendordate. Is the POlineExt correct path?

Try to find the "usrvendorDate" field where does it defined. may be in it is in PX.Objects.CN dll

Comment: Hi @saikiran unfortunately, it still doesn't make it enabled. and yes I have POlineExt in the correct path.

Comment: Can you add the field definition of "usrvendordate" in your question?  I mean code of "usrvendordate" DAC field.